# Setting up multi node Hadoop cluster automatically

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, configuration-management

I have an EC2 image that I made with Hadoop installed. However, I set it up to be roleless upon instantiation (it isn't a slave or a master). In order to start a Hadoop cluster I launch as many instances (nodes) as I need on EC2, then I have to do the 3 following things to each node:

1. Update /etc/hosts to contain the necessary IP addresses.
2. If master node, change $HADOOP_HOME/conf/masters and $HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves
3. Enable SSH access between the nodes.

I'd like to be able to find a way to do this automatically so that for an arbitrary amount of nodes, I don't have to go in and set all these settings on each one.

How do other people deal with setting up Hadoop clusters automatically? Is there a way to automate the networking part?

I'm not sure it would be possible since the IP addresses will be different every time, but I want to know what other people have tried or what is commonly used. Is there a good way to automate these processes so every time I set up a cluster for testing I don't have to do these for every node? I don't know much about Linux scripting, is this possible with a script? Or will I just have to deal with configuring every node manually?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using Amazon's Elastic MapReduce? I have worked with that over the past year and it works great - you create your JAR, load your data to S3 and just provide the number of machines you want to run and the type.

Comment: I should have clarified, the end goal is to have a cluster independent of AWS, CDH, etc. on our own set of servers. The servers aren't available yet though, so I made my own EC2 image with Hadoop installed on it. I've been using EC2 to test what we have until our servers are ready, but since I can't use it in the end, I was looking for an answer that didn't involve AWS or Cloudera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with Hadoop, but in general the task you have is called "configuration management". In general you write some "receipes" and define "roles" (master, slave) for your servers. Such a role may contain config files for services, to-be-installed packages, hostname changes, SSH keys etc. After the servers have initially started up, you can tell them which role they should be and they will install automatically.

There are different tools available for these tasks, examples are [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or [Salt](http://saltstack.org/). There is a [comparison available at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll definitely look in to that. I'm trying to find if there's any Hadoop-specific methods though. If I can't find anything this is definitely the route I'll take.

Comment: I have a similar need, almost two years later. Care to share how you solved you problem? @Eric

Comment: @Arun Jose Unfortunately I didn't stay on that project much longer after I posted this question, so I never got around to finding a good solution. If you do come up with a solid solution in the mean time, please post it as an answer to this question :)

Answer (score -1):

I was going thru to see if utilities like these exist but could not find any.

So I built an automation utility for "Hadoop provisioning automation" using python, salt and fabric.

There are quite a number of steps involved for getting a hadoop cluster ready.

- spin up by EC2 instances.
- creating security groups.
- setup ssh keys so that the instances master can ssh to slaves.
- Install JDK.
- Install hadoop.
- Designate nodes as namenode,secondary namenode, slaves -make hadoop
  config file changes..
- Start services

Doing all these things say for 4 nodes is going to take 1 hour. For the work I want to do, I need to do these repeatedly and often so with a large number of nodes hence the need for automation.

For steps that need to be done in every node (eg: jdk install, hadoop package install, etc) I used salt for configuration management. Salt provides similar capabilities like puppet and chef.

please feel free to check out
https://github.com/varmarakesh/aws-hadoop

If you already have an aws account,it is designed for easy setup and run.